# amd gpu installation proble

Tags: opencl

[I can't install amd gpu driver on ubnutu 20.10 (groovy gorilla) in my hp notebook. so I can not use any graphics design tools (gimp , DaVinci Rsolve 16 etc). My graphics driver model is amd R5 m330 . help me kindly....] How I will do properly installation on my hp notebook .

Comment: You don't need to install any driver to be able to use gimp, etc. What happens when you try to use gimp?

Comment: Thankswhen I work high resolution graphics then need graphic . Morevere must need for Davinci resolve 16? so what can I solve it?